# How to reconnect to Airport Extreme hard drive without rebooting

Tags: network, hard-drive, airport

I put a mac formatted hard drive on my export extreme. I can connect just fine. If I leave the house and use the computer outside I'll get a message about the drive not available and the option to disconnect. I pick that. Then when I get back home the Airport Extreme still shows up in the finder but clicking it I get the message

> "AirportExtreme" can't be opened because the original item can't be found

Rebooting my mac fixes the issue but that's no good because I lose the state of all my apps.

Is there fix for this issue? Either (a) a way to make it just work like it's supposed to or (b) some command I can run to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found one workaround which to option-click the Finder and pick "relaunch"

[image]